# How to solve the trigonometric inequality $\csc(2x) \leq \sec(x + \frac{\pi}{6})$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have difficulty in solving the inequality

> $\csc(2x) \leq \sec(x + \frac{\pi}{6})$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

First, I need to solve the equation $\csc(2x) - \sec(x + \frac{\pi}{6}) = 0$. I see that the period is $2\pi$. My problem is that I have no idea how to factor $\csc(2x) - \sec(x + \frac{\pi}{6})$. Which method can I use  to transform it into a product of basic trig equations? Or is there another way to solve this equation ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x = \sin \frac \pi2 - x \implies \sec (x + \frac{\pi}{6} = \csc(\frac {\pi}{3} -x)\\
\csc 2x \le \csc (\frac \pi3 - x)$

When the LHS and RHS have the same sign: (careful, it is more involved than it appears on the face of it to find these regions.)

$2x \ge \frac \pi3 - x\\
x \ge \frac {\pi}{9} + k\frac {2\pi}{3}$

Plus the regions were the $RHS >0$ and $LHS < 0$

And keep in mind that $\csc x$ is undefined at certain points.

Actually it is a little trickier than that.  [image]Here is a picture.

Comment: Thanks for this tip !

Comment: Actually I try to find the following solutions for hours : $2\pi n - \frac{2}{3}\pi < x \leq 2\pi n - \frac{5\pi}{9}, 2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{2} < x < 2\pi n, 2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{9} \leq x < 2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{3}, 2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2} < x \leq 2\pi n + \frac{2\pi}{3}, 2\pi n + \frac{7\pi}{9} \leq x < 2\pi n + \pi$.

Comment: does the picture help?  $x\in [\frac {\pi}{9} + 2k\pi,\frac {\pi}{3} + 2k\pi)\cup(\frac {7\pi}{9} + 2k\pi,\pi+ 2k\pi) \cup (\frac {4\pi}{3} + 2k\pi,\frac {13\pi}{9} + 2k\pi)\cup(\frac {3\pi}{2}+ 2k\pi, 2\pi + 2k\pi)$

Comment: For everything in Q4, $\csc 2x < 0$ and $\csc (\frac {\pi}{3} - x) > 0$

Answer (score -1):

your inequality can be simplified to
$$\frac{1}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}\le \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)}$$
substituting $$a=\sin(x),b=\cos(x)$$ we get
$$\frac{1}{ab}\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}b-a}$$ with $a^2+b^2=1$
this gives $$-\frac{a-\sqrt{3}b+4ab}{2ab(a-\sqrt{3}b)}\geq 0$$

Comment: Should it not be $sec(x + \frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} cos(x) - \frac{1}{2}sin(x)}$ ?

Comment: thank you very much for your hint! have a nice time!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your method is great! I now try to continue this exercise. I think the rest is easily done :).

Comment: we Can also compare our answers together

Comment: I would be very pleased if you could post your detailed solution. Your answer helped me a little bit further, but the rest of the exercise was not so easy for me than I thought  in the beginning :(. In fact, this is the first trigonometric inequality that I have to solve. I have only solved trig equations so far.